# Couchbase view results differ with reduce function

Tags: view, couchdb, mapreduce, couchbase

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.jsonType == 'cart') {
    if((Date.parse(doc.updated_at) + (15 * 60000)) >= Date.now()) {
      for(item in doc.items) {
        emit(item, doc.items[item].quantity);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this function I get the documents that have been updated within the last 15 minutes, for example 2, with quantity 1 and 2, which should result in 3 as a sum. However, when I use the built-in reduce function _sum, I get 32 (sum of all existing rows).

I updated the views several times, but still don't get the correct results.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong the use of `Date.now()` in map (and reduce) functions. Maps/reduce results are saved on disk for fast retrieval at query time. The value of `Date.now()` you get, is that of when the map was built, not when it's queried. You can find some introductory material on how CochDB's maps work on the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Restrictions_on_map_and_reduce_functions) and [The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html).

Comment: Thanks! So, the only solution is to use the date as key and work with startkey/endkey?

Comment: The Solution depends on your use-case, however putting the date in the key is certainly a good technique for querying by date.